# RCP application: "Check for Updates" returns "No updates were found"

Tags: eclipse-rcp, equinox, p2

I'm updating the RCP application from the site, which contains the new version of the application (9.0.0.46).
But "Check for Updates" returns "No updates were found".
Example:
existing version is 9.0.0.7;
new version is 9.0.0.46.

For the existing version 9.0.0.13 the new version (9.0.0.46) was found.

It seems that versions are compared as a Strings, and as 4 < 7 the RCP doesn't see the new version in the first case, and as 4 > 1 it sees the second one.
How to check this assumption and resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the fourth part of the version is not considered at all, it is usually just a build qualifier value (not a number).

Comment: It's nice to hear from you again, @greg-449! Last time [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66265812/6863550) you helped me a lot! 
If I understand correctly, only first 3 numbers are considered, lets say in my case: 9.0.0. So to make the new version I should do, for example: 9.0.1.
Yet, it's steel strange that in one case the new version was found, but in the other it wasn't. And these versions differ only be qualifiers.

Comment: I don't use the p2 code so I'm not sure what the exact rules are. But the 4th part can definitely be anything so it won't be treating it as a number and any comparison will be string based. So I think changing the major/minor/micro values is what you are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in the https://wiki.eclipse.org/Version_Numbering. In RCP applications,
the build number is composed of four (4) segments: three integers and a string, respectively named `major.minor.service.qualifier`.
While the first three segments (`major`, `minor` and `service`) are compared as numbers, the last one (`qualifier`) is compared lexicographically.
So, in my case, it is actually an expected behavior.